# General purpose computing on GPU

Tags: development, gpu, opencl

I've recently moved to Mac. And even though I like OS X itself, I find it way too outdated in terms of working with GPU based calculations.

I realize that notebook is not the best thing for heavy computing, but even regarding study projects it's quite outdated.

I realized that due to AMD my CUDA adventures would have to stop, but I really counted on OpenCL which appears to be v1.2, while there's 3.0 is out.

And it does not seem to be replaced with something. E.g. Keras uses PlaidML, which is based on that utterly outdated CL version.

I obviously see bootcamp as one of the solutions, but is there anything which would allow me to use OS X while still having an ability to run experiments with parallel computing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I kind of found Metal, but question still persists since I'd rather work with something more portable.

UPD: And yes, plaidml appears to have metal backend.

Comment: Is this an actual answer to your question or is it additional info that should be in your question?

Comment: @fsb I'd say it's half of answer. The point is that apple seem to have gone it's own way. The question "Is there anything more widely-used which would make my knowledge more portable" still persists. 

I cannot accept my answer right now and close the thread due to time constraints set up by stack exchange.